# bash control statment for when an option flag is used

Tags: bash, options

I trying to make control statement to check on a option flag is used or not?  For -o output.file if is used I would like to make equal to variable OUTPUTSUM = OUTPUTFILE and if there no -o option use then I have it defaulted to relative path of the script? I just not sure how to go about checking for -o option?

PSEUDO code

```
while getopts i:o:h OPTION
do
     case $OPTION in
         i)
             INPUTFILE=$OPTARG
             ;;
     o)
         OUTPUTFILE=$OPTARG
             ;;
         h)
             usage
         exit 1
             ;;
         ?)
             usage
             exit
             ;;
     esac
done

if [-o EXIST]; then

    OUTPUTSUM = OUTPUTFILE
else
   OUTPUTSUM = $SCRIPTPATH/SUMMARY
fi
```

Comment: Bash doesn't have a `-o output.file` option...

Comment: I code it. I will add the code.

Comment: Don't cross post questions, please. I deleted the one on Super User.

Comment: Using the shell for more than trivial(ish) scripts is for masochists (or SysVinit lovers). Learn a more featureful scripting language (Python, Perl, Ruby) if you regularly find yourself writing scripts.

Comment: What inhibits shell from being featureful language?  Not enough community support?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

bash [parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion): use default value if variable is unset or null:

```
outputsum=${outputfile:-"$scriptpath/SUMMARY"}
```

Get out of the habit of using `$ALL_CAPS_VARNAMES` -- one day you'll use "PATH" and break your script.

Comment: Thank you and thank you for your advice. I'm going through all my code now and changing most of my variables. This work.

Comment: `$ALL_CAPS_VARNAMES` mostly used for environment variable

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Variables